# JavaScript Get specific span value "ng-style"

Tags: javascript, angularjs-ng-style

Code is:

```
<span ng-style="item.disable_method?{'opacity':'.5'}:{}" class="ng-binding">Credit Card</span>
<span ng-style="item.disable_method?{'opacity':'.5'}:{}" class="ng-binding">Debit Card</span>
```

And many similer span.

I want to use `document.querySelector(span[ng-style="item.disable_method?{'opacity':'.5'}:{}"]`) to get value `Credit Card` but i am receiving something different payment method as all the span id is same.

Edit:

My question was not clear. I want to get a reference to the first one.

Like `var payment_Method = document.querySelector` or any method so i can use like `payment_Method.innerHTML` to get "Credit Card" return

> How can i get it correct? maybe loop or something.

can't user `document.getElementsByClassName('ng-binding')[Change_Able_Value].innerText` as value change.

Comment: do you want the innerHTML of the first span?

Comment: @DCR Thous are items inside a collapse. I want to check the innerHTML and click on the item to select it.

Comment: @DCR Thank you for your time. I need something different. I have updated the post can you please take another look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var classes=document.getElementsByClassName('ng-binding');
var element;
for(let i = 0;i<classes.length;i++){
   console.log(i);
   if(classes[i].innerHTML == "Credit Card")element = classes[i];
}
console.log(element.innerHTML);
```

```html
<span ng-style="item.disable_method?{'opacity':'.5'}:{}" class="ng-binding" >Credit Card</span>
<span ng-style="item.disable_method?{'opacity':'.5'}:{}" class="ng-binding" >Debit Card</span>
```

Comment: Sorry, My question was not clear. I want to get a reference to the first one. Like var payment_Method= document or any method so i can use like payment_Method.innerHTML to get "Credit Card" return

Comment: answer updated.  let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Tried this method document.getElementsByClassName('ng-binding');. There are more than 1000 ng-binding class and the location for Credit Card [0] value change every time. In the real code some times [33], [87] etc. So i can't use this.

Comment: you need to provide a complete description of your problem. can you supply link to website?.  Do you know that you want to get the element that has Credit Card as innerHTML?

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close as your question lacks clarity as to what you actually want

Comment: I am confused how can i describe the problem, Sorry. Yes, I know the innerHTML value i need. This is login only page.

Comment: I tried the code. If i tried the loop with Credit Card then all the innerHTML on class ng-binding change to Credit Card. If i tried Debit Card all change to Debit Card. Strange!

Comment: sorrry about that, missing == in the if statement.  Updated.  Should work now.

Comment: Thank You. Solved my problem. Is there any using method "span ng-style"?

Comment: if it's working, please accept answer.  how many span ng-style tags do you have and how many ng-binding class tags do you have? if the span tags are fewer we can use those

Comment: There are many ng-binding, it change depends on website content. I think span ng-style is very few.

Comment: span ng-style only 6. I got it. I have edited your loop for document.querySelectorAll. Thank You so much for your time, sir. Be safe from the China Virus.